# How to Write Differences in Two Text Files to Another Text File in C?

Tags: c, file, text, io, difference

I'd like to write a program that compares two files and writes every byte in file one that is different from file two into a third file.  I want to compare the files byte by byte and write any differing single bytes to the third file.  I'm not very familiar with file I/O.  Can someone give me an example program that accomplishes this task?

This is what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int file1, file2, file1size, file2size;
  // int  difference1, difference2;
  char buf;

  if (argc != 3){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s <file1> <file2>", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }
  if ((file1 = open(argv[1], 0400)) < 0) { //read permission for user on file source
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open source");
    exit(1);
  }
  if ((file2 = open(argv[2], 0400)) < 0) { //read permission for user on file source
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open source");
    exit(1);
  }
  file1size = lseek(file1, (off_t) 0, SEEK_END);
  printf("File 1's size is %d\n", file1size);
  file2size = lseek(file2, (off_t) 0, SEEK_END);
  printf("File 2's size is %d\n", file2size);



}
```

I'm not sure how to compare file1 and file2's bytes and then write the differences to another file.

Comment: Welcome to SO - What have you tried so far? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2):

This is close to what you are looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; !feof(file1) || !feof(file2); i++) {
        int byte1 = getc(file1);
        int byte2 = getc(file2);
        if(byte1 != byte2) {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", i, byte1, byte2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It takes the two files as command line arguments and compares the two byte-by-byte. If two bytes are different, it printf the character #, and the ASCII values of the two characters. -1 means EOF was already reached.

You'll have to (understand and) adapt this to the output format you want. (I'm assuming this is homework.)

`feof` tests for end-of-file.

`getc` gets the next character (byte) from the file. It is -1 if the end of the file has been reached.

And you seem already to know what `printf` does.

Comment: Consider checking the return of fopen(). printf(file3,... ?

Comment: @CharlieBurns, sorry. That was leftover from the OP's request to print to a third file. Then, in his example, he printed to stdout. So I (incompletely) refactored.

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want, compiles, and runs,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int offset;
    int argi=1;
    int ch1, ch2;
    FILE *fh1, *fh2, *fh3=stdout;
        FILE *fh4=stdout;
    if( argc<3 ) {
        printf("usage: diff <file> <file> { <outfile> }\n"); return(1);
    }
    if(argi<argc) {
        if(!(fh1 = fopen(argv[argi], "r"))) {
            printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[argi]); return(2);
        }
    }
    if(++argi<argc) {
        if(!(fh2 = fopen(argv[argi], "r"))) {
            printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[argi]); return(3);
        }
    }
    if(++argi<argc) {
        if(!(fh3 = fopen(argv[argi], "w+"))) {
            printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[argi]); return(4);
        }
    }
        if(++argi<argc) {
            //duplicate output to a second file?
            if(!(fh4 = fopen(argv[argi], "r"))) {
                printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[argi]); return(3);
            }
        }
    for(offset = 0; (!feof(fh1)) && (!feof(fh2)); offset++)
    {
        ch1=ch2='-';
        if(!feof(fh1)) ch1 = getc(fh1);
        if(!feof(fh2)) ch2 = getc(fh2);
        if(ch1 != ch2) {
            fprintf(fh3,"%d:%c %c\n", offset, ch1, ch2);
            //additional file here
        }
        else {
            fprintf(fh3,"%c\n", ch1);
            //additional file here
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

More typically, you would read entire lines using fgets, and strcmp to compare the lines.  Here is how,

```
    char str1[1024], str2[1024];
    ...
    for(offset = 0; (!feof(fh1)) && (!feof(fh2)); offset++)
    {
        strcpy(str1,"-");strcpy(str2,"-");
        if(!feof(fh1)) fgets(str1,sizeof(str1),fh1);
        if(!feof(fh2)) fgets(str2,sizeof(str1),fh2);
        if(strcmp(str1,str2)!=0) 
            fprintf(fh3,"%d:%s  %s", offset, str1, str2);
        else
            fprintf(fh3,"%c", str1);
    }
```

Comment: This prints the differences of the text files to the output.  How would you put the differences into a third newly created txt file?

Comment: Notice that an optional third argument to the command line can be given to name an output file.  If that argument is omitted, then stdout is used.  The fprintf(fh3,...) prints either to stdout or the named file.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have another question.  Supposed there is a new file fh4. I want the program to output the same characters to both fh3 and fh4.  I tried:                                                 if(argc>3) {
        if(!(fh3 = fopen(argv[3], "w+"))) {
            printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[3]); return(4);
        }
 if(!(fh4 = fopen(argc[4], "w+"))){
 printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[4]); return(5);
 }
    }                                                                         However, I get an error that says "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer".

Comment: Added notes where to add a second output file.  But file copy works too.  Oh, accept the answer if it is what you need.